# How to close multiple nautilus folders that are opening automatically after login?

Tags: nautilus, folder

Every time after I login into Ubuntu
5 folders from the same path (/usr/share/applications) are opening automatically
I searched in Nautilus Help and I couldn’t find anything related to my issue.

**How to close multiple nautilus folders that are opening automatically after login?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Goto System **→** Preferences **→** Startup Applications
- In the options tab uncheck **Automatically remember running applications when logging out**.

  [image]

Comment: Sorry but I already check that and it's not checked..  It seems it something kept in memory so I have to purge/clearcache it from somewhere else

Comment: You'll have to uncheck that *after* you close all the applications and folders you don't wnat to open on boot; then uncheck and click "remember currently running applications"